# AWS: SSH to EC2 with Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface (EB CLI) 3.x

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a new Elastic Beanstalk (eb) application with Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface (EB CLI) Version 3.x.

Everything works so far, but I want to know how I can access the EC2-instance via SSH without using the `eb ssh` command. Reason is, I want to open a connection with `sshfs`.

What I know is, that the eb commandline tool uses a `aws-eb` keypair, which is located in my `~/.ssh` folder. I tried to connect to the EC2 by calling `ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws-eb ec2-user@myenv.elasticbeanstalk.com` but nothing happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to connect to the ec2 instance directly using its public ip address. You can not connect using the elasticbeanstalk url.

You can find the instance ip address by looking it up in the ec2 console.

You also need to make sure port 22 is open. By default the EB CLI closes port 22 after a ssh connection is complete. You can call `eb ssh -o` to keep the port open after the ssh session is complete.

**Warning**: You should know that elastic beanstalk could replace your instance at anytime. State is not guaranteed on any of your elastic beanstalk instances. Its probably better to use ssh for testing and debugging purposes only, as anything you modify can go away at any time.

Comment: Oh yes you are right, I was able to login successfully only after `eb ssh -o` so that port 22 is kept open. I thought the default security-group is always opened on eb-instances. Thanks!